# How to add comments to a zip file

Tags: zip, comments

I have research some days and found that we can add a file with some contents to the zip file and then compress it again. then the comments will be added to the zip file, but i don't know what that file exactly is, so any one know the principle for adding comments to a zip(compressed) file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-c` parameter will let you add a one-line comment for each file in the zip interactively. E.g. `zip -c valid.zip somefile.txt`

The `-z` parameter will let you add a multi-line comment for the entire zip archive interactively. E.g. `zip -z valid.zip somefile.txt`

Answer (score 3):

For command-line use, feed the per-file comments (`-c`) and/or the per-zip comment (`-z`) to `stdin`. When using *both*, feed in the per-file comments first (one line each), followed by the per-zip comment line (s). Example:

```
$ touch one.txt two.txt

$ zip -c -z commented.zip one.txt two.txt <<END
> Comment for one
> Comment for two
> Remaining lines are zip-level comment
> lines. There can be more than one line here.
> End with a dot:
> .
> END
  adding: one.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: two.txt (stored 0%)
Enter comment for one.txt:
Enter comment for two.txt:
enter new zip file comment (end with .):

$ unzip -l commented.zip 
Archive:  commented.zip
Remaining lines are zip-level comment
lines. There can be more than one line here.
End with a dot:
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  11-13-2019 10:06   one.txt
Comment for one
        0  11-13-2019 10:06   two.txt
Comment for two
---------                     -------
        0                     2 files
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the manual for your version of zip.  On the Macintosh, the -c parameter will allow you to add a comment line.

Comment: what's the differences between -c and -z parameter? and how can i set the comments within the command rather than input it when the terminal request?